# Can i call a constructor inside a other constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, nested

```
class Address 
{ 
    public string Street { get; set; }  
    public string City { get; set; }  
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }  
    public string Country { get; set; }  
    
    public Address(string street, string city, string zipCode, string country)  
    { 
        Street = street;  
        City = city;  
        ZipCode = zipCode;  
        Country = country; 
    }  
}
```

```
class Customer
{
    Address address { get; set; }
    BirthDate birthDaty{ get; set; }
    int NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
    DriveType driveType { get; set; }
    CarBrand carBrand { get; set; }
    
    public Customer(Address address = new Address()) 
    {
    }
}
```

I got this code, and I try to call the constructor for `Address` inside the `Customer` constructor because I don't want to declare and initialize Street, City, ZipCode and Country again. Could someone help me how to do it inheritance.

I already tried to call the constructor with the parameters but nothing works.

Comment: Also, question aside. You should reconsider the composition of your objects. For example, `NumberOfSeats` being associated with a specific customer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb some customers need more than one seat... I'm more interested in what driveType for a customer would be - probably "money", "fame", "sins",... :). At least carBrand makes sense (also probably should be list as some accept more than BMW as a car brand).

Comment: Use internal constructor

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to initialize the address as a parameter?
Try this instead :

```
class Customer
{
    Address address { get; set; }
    BirthDate birthDaty{ get; set; }
    int NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
    DriveType driveType { get; set; }
    CarBrand carBrand { get; set; }

    public Customer(string street, string city, string zipCode, string country) 
    {
         this.address = new Address(street, city, zipCode, country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create nonconstant defaults. Use an overloaded constructor.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    
    public Customer() : this(new Address()) { }
    public Customer(Address address) 
    {
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```

an alternative to the above that results in the same code is

```
public class Customer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; } = new Address();
    
    public Customer()
    {
    }
    public Customer(Address address) 
    {
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```

But if you want to construct an `Address` inside `Customer` then add a constructor with the parameters needed, like so.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    
    public Customer(string street, string city, string zip, string country)
    {
       this.Address = new Address(street,city,zip,country);
    }
    public Customer(Address address) 
    {
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```

---

PS. I suggest sticking to the naming conventions for C# by using Capitalized names for properties and leaving small-caps for fields and local variables.